# WebAPI aborted and cancelled

Tags: httprequest, asp.net-core-webapi, payload

I have created a WebAPI that takes a payload of 500MB+.
It is being used externally at 200+ sites.
Every so often when a site is using the API to send the payload (which is normally about 4MB max), the API call get the bellow error.

> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

When a site gets this error, I can take the same payload and use the SAME api, but from my location and the API does not return any error.

Could the issue be their side (*Like firewall*) as it works here each time.  So no issue with the payload or API.

The payload contains encrypted data!

Has anyone had this issue before and if so how did they go around resolving this?

Comment: There could be any number of different causes. There's not enough here to diagnose your issue. At the minimum, post the code for the action, as maybe you'll get lucky and there's something you can improve/fix there. Otherwise, you're just going to have to start digging into your network. Add logging to everything, if you haven't already. Perhaps you can at least share the logs, if there's no sensitive information. That might help as well.

Comment: Without seeing logs, any number of things could have happened. If I was a betting man, I would put it to some type of socket disruption.

Comment: Hi thanks for for the comments Chris and ATerry.  The solution first sends a short get call to get a transaction.  Then a Post with a payload is sent, This post does not get through to the API and I only get the below log. Message: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
StackTrace: at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)

Comment: I will get code and see if I can get in touch with the external site for their logs.  Again thanks